# MPI multiple choice

Tags: c++, mpi

i'm newbie here..
i have a problem with my code, i don't know how to make a multiple choice in MPI..
if there is 2 function process, 
1. Process A 
2. Process B 
3. exit 
"What you want to do? answer : " 
if i run my code with 1 device (mpiexec -n 1), there is no problem.
 But if more than one device, it gets error. I want to all 'id' do this process..master and slave.

```
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Get_processor_name (namenode, &namelen);
int answer;
if(myid==0){
    while(answer!=3){
        cout<<"1.Process A"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Process B"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"choose your answer: ";
        cin>>answer;

        if(answer==1){
            function A;
        }
        else if(answer==2){
            function B;
        }
        else {
        }
    }
}
```

thank you..sorry if my explanation isn't good.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?  Where is the rest of your code and what does it do ?  The fragment you've shown us doesn't call MPI_Finalize so I'm not surprised 'it gets error', I'm more surprised that it does execute when you only use 1 processor. It's unusual to see an MPI code with user interaction through the console, the default configuration on most MPI installations is to run programs unattached to a console.

Comment: i forgot to put the MPI_Bcast..
before your answer, i put MPI_Bcast inside "if(answer==1 or 2)"..
i thought that MPI_Bcast function is to broadcast the value..
i'm newbie in MPI..thank you for your help..if i have another problems, please help me again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like all MPI processes to execute a function based on a dialog performed in process `0`, then you would have to do something like this:

```
int answer = -1;

while (answer != 3) {
    if (myid == 0) {
        cout << "1.Process A" << endl;
        cout << "2.Process B" << endl;
        cout << "3.exit" << endl;
        cout << "choose your answer: ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&answer, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (answer == 1) {
        function A;
    }
    else if (answer == 2) {
        function B;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

It works like this: process `0` reads the desired answer from the user, then the answer is broadcasted from process `0` to all the other processes. Then every process (including process `0`) branches in accordance to the value of `answer`. Then it loops again until something other than `1` or `2` was entered.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help..now,i want to try this parallel, hope it works well..

Comment: Hi Mr. Hristo, may i have your email? i want to share the rest of my code with you..there are another problems with my code..if you don't mind of course..thank you

Comment: @Faris, unfortunately my schedule is very tight those days. I would advise you to post your questions here, where other people will see them too and you'll get response quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems but I'm not 100% sure if I've understood you correctly.
When `myid = 0` then the only option you have is to press 3 because else it will never exit the loop.

So it's not possible to call function A or function B

Comment: oke, i will try to explain again, sorry if my explanation is wrong.. i want to show the option of process only on root's device, but the process that i chose, it will be run on all of device..root and slave.. How to do that?

Comment: i had edit my code, please check again, and please help me to solve my problem..thank you